# Время с момента запуска программы

Tags: c++, время

Как вывести в командную строку время в минутах, после того как программа запустилась ?

Comment: для какой операционной системы ?

Comment: Windows 7 на Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @Nick  Простейшее - это использовать старндартную  C функцию asctime

Answer (score 5):

Если требуется выводить время, прошедшее с момента запуска программы и не бояться перевода системных часов, то можно воспользоваться следующим [кодом](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VixvpRt4tT1Bo5TD) (c++11 и выше):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now(); // запоминаем время начала

int main()
{
   this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2)); // какая-то полезная деятельность 
   auto current = chrono::steady_clock::now(); // время в момент проверки
   cout << "Work time: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(current - start).count() << " sec.\n";
}
```

В примере показаны секунды, чтобы можно было посмотреть результат в онлайн-компиляторе.

Comment: Всегда было интересно, кто автор до такой степени, гм... извращенной записи работы со временем в стандарте? Просто выламывается из всего остального стандарта...

Comment: @Harry а что именно смущает?

Comment: Многословность и опосредованность...

Comment: @Harry позволяющая тем не менее выбирать любые временные интервалы не вводя разные функции для (секунд/миллисекунд/наносекунд...), и не использовать записи вида `sleep(1000000000);`, когда нужно ожидать 1 секунду, а параметр принимает значение в наносекундах. Всё это основано на классе `std::ratio` по-большому счету.

Answer (score 2):

Воспринимая ваш вопрос как "время, прошедшее после запуска программы", я бы действовал примерно так:

```
int main()
{
    time_t start_time = time(0);

    ...

    cout << (time(0)-start_time)/60 << " минут";
```

Если вы имеете в виду что-то другое - укажите более точно, что именно вам нужно.

Переменную можно сделать глобальной - тогда инициализируется даже до `main()` :)

Comment: Теперь главное, чтобы никто не стал трогать системные часы.

Comment: @alexolut Само собой :)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ с англоязычного форума [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/997988/3240681)

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
    cout << (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-' 
         << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
         <<  now->tm_mday
         << endl;
}
```